# How to plot 'log' and 'first difference of log' in R?

Tags: r

This might sound easy question to some people, but I am a beginner in R and I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

So, basically, I have uploaded my excel data into R. I have three variables. The first variable is in the format of the date (1994-01-03), the other two are just numbers.

[dataset looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXWwj.png)

I have plotted my main graphs using this command:

> plot(dataset$observation_date,dataset$interest_rate,t="l", xlab = "Observation date" , ylab = "Interest Rate")

Now I need to plot a graph of the "log" and "first difference of log" of two variables.

Big thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please share a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) snipped of your data by adding the output of `dput(dataset)` into your question?

Comment: That said, you can calculate the log with `log(x)` or `log10(x)` depending on your needs, and the first difference perhaps with `diff(log(x))`. But with your actual data it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Just the log.

From `help("plot.default")`:

> log
> a character string which contains "x" if the x axis is to be logarithmic, "y" if the y axis is to be logarithmic and "xy" or "yx" if both axes are to be logarithmic.

And here is a reproducible example.

```r
plot(1:10, 1:10,
     type = "l", xlab = "Observation date" , ylab = "Interest Rate",
     log = "y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### 2. log and diff log

To plot both the log and the first differences of the log, here are two ways.

```r
plot(1:10, 1:10,
     type = "l", xlab = "Observation date" , ylab = "Interest Rate",
     xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 10))
lines(1:10, log(1:10))
lines(2:10, diff(log(1:10)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### 3. log and diff log (cont.)

The second way is more clear if an auxiliary function to compute the diff logs is defined.

```r
dl <- function(x) c(0, diff(log(x)))
plot(1:10, 1:10,
     type = "l", xlab = "Observation date" , ylab = "Interest Rate",
     xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 10))
curve(log, from = 1, to = 10, add = TRUE)
curve(dl, from = 1, to = 10, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you want this all on one plot, you are going to need to use the `lines()` function and play around with the specifics such as the line types etc.

The code I have is:

```r
# Creating some dummy data
dt<-data.frame(time=c(1:10),
               interest_rate = c(1:10))

dt$logged_interest<- log(dt$interest_rate)
# Make blank column
dt$logged_diff<- NA
# First difference excludes the first term
dt$logged_diff[2:10]<- diff(dt$logged_interest)

# The Plot
plot(dt$time,dt$interest_rate,
     type = "l", 
     xlab = "Time" , 
     ylab = "Interest Rate",
     ylim=c(-1,10),
     main="Interest Rates over Time")
lines(dt$time,dt$logged_interest,lty=2)
lines(dt$time,dt$logged_diff,lty=3)
legend("bottomright", 
       legend=c("Interest Rate", 
                "Logged Interest Rate",
                "First Difference of Log"),
       lty=1:3, cex=0.8)
```

[image]

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for plotting a graph of the "log" of two variables:

```
x = log(dataset$observation_date)
y = log(dataset$interest_rate)
plot(x, y,
     type = "l", 
     xlab = "Observation date", 
     ylab = "Interest Rate")
```

You can use the following code for plotting a graph of the "first difference of log" of two variables:

```
x = diff(log(dataset$observation_date))
y = diff(log(dataset$interest_rate))
plot(x, y,
     type = "l", 
     xlab = "Observation date", 
     ylab = "Interest Rate")
```